# pgfplot basic linear plot question

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot this simple graph resembling the graph below

[image: Example plot]

So far I've figured out how to graph some basics using the below but don't know how to plot coordinate and y-intercept along with the line

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathexam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\ExamHead{\today}

\let\ds\displaystyle

\begin{document}
\ExamInstrBox{
Please show \textbf{all} your work! Answers without supporting work will not be marked. Write answers in spaces provided. You have 1 hour to complete this exam.}
\ExamNameLine
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Find the equation of these lines
    \begin{enumerate}
       \item \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel = x, ylabel = y, axis lines=center, axis on top=true]
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=black,ultra thick] {1/2*x+3};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \answer
        \item \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel = x, ylabel = y, axis lines=center, axis on top=true]
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=black,ultra thick] {3*x-1};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \answer

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar thank you for your input. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit modified @PeterGrill answer (+1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$,
    x label style={anchor=west},
    y label style={anchor=south},
    axis equal,
    xtick=\empty,   ytick=\empty,           % <---
    extra x ticks=0,
    x tick label style={anchor=north east}, % <---
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=5.5,                    % <---
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=5.5,                    % <---
            ]
\addplot [red,domain=-3:5,very thick, <->] {1/2*x+3};
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {(4,1/2*4+3)} node[above left] {(2,4)};
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {(0,1/2*0+3)} node[above left] {(0,3)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `\addplot coordinates`  to place a point at the desired point:

```
\addplot [draw=none, mark=*] coordinates{(4,5)} node [left] {(4,5)};
```

[image]

### Notes

- Also, the axis labels should be in math mode. I have modified those in the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathexam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagecolor{white}

\ExamHead{\today}

\let\ds\displaystyle

\begin{document}
\ExamInstrBox{
Please show \textbf{all} your work! Answers without supporting work will not be marked. Write answers in spaces provided. You have 1 hour to complete this exam.}
\ExamNameLine
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Find the equation of these lines
    \begin{enumerate}
       \item \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, axis lines=center, axis on top=true]
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=black,ultra thick] {1/2*x+3};
            \addplot [draw=none, mark=*] coordinates{(4,5)}
                node [above left] {(4,5)};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \answer
        \item \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, axis lines=center, axis on top=true]
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=black,ultra thick] {3*x-1};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \answer

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```